# Noun form of "scared" for "feeling of [blank] "

Tags: word-formation

Which form of the word **scare** would complete the phrase *feeling of ..* It might be something like **afraidness**. I don't think **scariness** works here.

Comment: Something like feeling of **dread**?

Comment: Could it be *fear*?

Comment: What's wrong with *scare* "**1** A sudden attack of fright" to start with?  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/scare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to have something cognate with *scare* then your best bet would be the noun phrase "being scared".

You'd likely do better though with *fear*, *dread*, *fright* or a synonym of one of those.

Comment: Thank you. I realized _fear_ is the correct word to use soon after.

Answer (score 1):

There is the noun form ***scaredness***, however it is not a common word like *fear* and "feeling of scaredness" isn't a useful phrase. *Scare* itself is used as a noun also, meaning sudden fear.

> *scaredness:* the quality or state of being scared
>
> *scare:* a sudden feeling of fear
>
> [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary)

"Feeling of scare" is somewhat acceptable but it is not a common phrase also. I see the usage in psychological contexts.

Example from the book "Integration in Counselling & Psychotherapy: Developing a Personal Approach" *By Phil Lapworth, Charlotte Sills*:

> For example, the therapist may simply say,'You look scared right now' in response to facial and bodily clues of fear, in order to facilitate the client in acknowledging, contacting and expressing their **feeling of scare**.